# Unique identifier not recognized by SQL query

Tags: r, shiny, rsqlite

I am making a table for users to fill out in Shiny using SQLite. At the end of each session I want to delete all entries containing the unique sessionID:

```
library(RSQLite)
library(pool)
library(DBI)

#Generates unique token. For example "ce20ca2792c26a702653ce54896fc10a"
sessionID <- session$token 

pool <- dbPool(RSQLite::SQLite(), dbname = "db.sqlite")

df <- data.frame( sessionID=character(), 
                  name=character(),
                  group=character(),
                  stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

dbWriteTable(pool, "user_data", df, overwrite=FALSE, append=TRUE)

-------------#Code to fill out the table-----------------
```

At the end of the session I delete the session specific entries using:

```
dbExecute(pool, sprintf('DELETE FROM "user_data" WHERE "sessionID" == (%s)', sessionID))
```

I get the following error:

> Warning: Error in result_create: no such column: ce20ca2792c26a702653ce54896fc10a

If I replace the session ID with a random generated number for example "4078540723057" the entries are deleted without any problem. Why is the session$token not recognized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the `sessionId` column is text in your SQLite database, SQLite expects the literal value to be surrounded in single quotes.  Normally you would use a prepared statement for this, but you may try:

```
dbExecute(pool, sprintf("DELETE FROM user_data WHERE sessionID = '%s'", sessionID))
```

Waiving the need to use a prepared statement here may be justified as your script is not open/accessible to the outside.